# Operating System wide language localization?

Tags: c, localization, internationalization

I have always wondered how OSs such as Windows or Mac OS X can just change languages in 1 click and all a sudden, all message boxes, buttons etc are changed.

How are these sorts of mechanisms implemented?

Thanks

Comment: By replacing all the text with different text?  I don't really understand what you're querying here...

Comment: [The same way the applications do it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization)

Comment: When the button is initialized, where does it get the text from, so does this stay organized.

Comment: +1 to offset the downvote.  Internationalization is important, and even though this is a basic question, it's extremely relevant.

Comment: @AdamLiss: I didn't downvote, but I imagine that it might have come about because the scope/focus of the question is unclear.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Is it really?  Did my answer miss the boat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to internationalization is to avoid hard-coding any text that will be seen by the user.  Instead, call a function that checks the locale and chooses the text appropriately.

A contrived example:

```
// A "database" of the word "hello" in various languages.
struct _hello {
  char *language;
  char *word;
} hello[] = {
  { "English", "Hello" },
  { "French", "Bon jour" },
  { "Spanish", "Buenos dias" },
  { "Japanese", "Konnichiwa" },
  { null, null }
};

// Print, e.g. "Hello, Milo!"
void printHello(char *name) {
  printf("%s, %s!\n", say_hello(), name);
}

// Choose the word for "hello" in the appropriate language,
// as set by the (fictitious) environment variable LOCALE
char *say_hello() {
  // Search until we run out of languages.
  for (struct _hello *h = hello; h->language != null; ++h) {
    // Found the language, so return the corresponding word.
    if (strcmp(h->language, getenv(LOCALE)) == 0) {
      return h->word;
    }
  }
  // No language match, so default to the first one.
  return hello->word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On UNIX-like systems,the messages are [catalogs and stored in files](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Locating-Catalogs).
Programmatically,the C provides the [`gettext()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) function for Internationalization and localization and the [locale.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/locale.h.html) header for get cultute information.

Here's an code example taken at [here](http://oriya.sarovar.org/docs/gettext_single.html)

```
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
 setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );
 bindtextdomain( "hello", "/usr/share/locale" );
 textdomain( "hello" );
 printf( gettext( "Hello, world!\n" ) );
 exit(0);
}
```

On MS-Windows,it uses the [`MUI(Multilingual User Interface)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilingual_User_Interface). Programmatically in C you can use the [`LoadString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Check out [`how to do`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194810.aspx).